# Displaying HashTable Data In JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hashtable

I Have a hash Table

```
hashtable c = new Hashtable();

Employee emp = new Employee("E1001","Sky");
c.put("E1001",emp);
```

Then I have a JTable

```
Object[][] data = {

                {"", ""},

        };

String[] headers = {"Employee Code", "Employee First Name"};
JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
```

I Cant seem to Figure out how to add the `hashtable` items into the `JTable`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, something like...

```
Object[][] data = new Object[c.size()][2];
int row = 0;
for (Object key : c.keySet()) {
    data[row][0] = key;
    Employee emp = (Employee)c.get(key);
    data[row][1] = ...; // Get name from Employee object...
    // Personally, I prefer to assign the Employee object to
    // the column of the row and use a TableCellRenderer to
    // renderer it
}

String[] headers = {"Employee Code", "Employee First Name"};
JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
```

Should work...

Now, if you want a stronger relationship between the `HashMap` and `TableModel` (so you could add content to the table and it would update the `HashMap`), you're going to need to use an `AbstractTableModel` and get your hands dirty mapping the content between the requirements of the model and the `HashMap`